# How are integers stored in iOS, in particular in .pList and CoreData

Tags: ios, numbers, integer, storage

I am trying to take a small integer (eg 4) from a pList and put it into a managed object for later manipulation. However, by the time I come to take it out of the managed object and put it into an NSInteger it has changed completely. 4 has become 237371328 !

The number is stored as "Number" in the pList and integer 16 in the managed object.
I have two fields: timesAsNumber which is integer 16 and timesUsed which is string (my current work around!).

The lines of code involved are:

```
NSArray *usageFetchResults = [self.objectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSLog(@"Here is the usageArray: %@, with error: %@",usageFetchResults, error);
```

This gives the log result:

data: {\n    feature = video;\n    timesAsNumber = 4;\n    timesUsed = 4;\n})"
), with error: (null)

So the logger knows the value of timesAsNumber is 4.

```
NSLog(@"timesAsNumber straight from the Managed Object: %@", [currentUseData valueForKey:@"timesAsNumber"]);
```

Produces result: timesAsNumber straight from the Managed Object: 4  so still no problem.

However,

```
NSInteger timesUsedAsInt = [currentUseData valueForKey:@"timesAsNumber"];
NSLog(@"times As Number now reads: %ld", (long)timesUsedAsInt);
```

Produces the result: times As Number now reads: 237371328

I need to have the number as an integer for manipulation and my workaround of storing as string and converting to and fro is hardly elegant!

I teach High School computing so I know about storage of floating point numbers: excess-127, twos complement etc. I assume the problem arises from the different ways the integer is stored in the pList, the managed object and the NSInteger. However, I cannot figure out what those storage methods are so that I can work with them.

Any help gratefully received.

Tim.

Comment: Did the compiler not warn about "incompatible pointer to integer conversion"?

Comment: Only when I tried to assign the value to an int or unsigned int. NSInteger was happy. I think Levi's answer is going to work. I am away from my machine at the moment so I'll come back later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are storing a number in `plist` or `coreData`, it is stored as NSNumber. So you access the value as `NSInteger myInt = myNumber.intValue`. When you are converting it back, use `NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt]`. That large number (237371328) could appear because you forgot to convert the `NSNumber` to `int`. Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

Try:

```
NSInteger timesUsedAsInt = [[currentUseData valueForKey:@"timesAsNumber"] intValue];
NSLog(@"times As Number now reads: %ld", (long)timesUsedAsInt);
```

Comment: Thanks very much Levi, your suggested code worked perfectly. I did not expect the apparently simple pList and managed objects to be as sophisticated as NSNumber. I am sure you are right about the origin of the very large integers: I think I was shoving 2 random bytes of the NSNumber object into the space for an int variable and getting rubbish out!